# Can't load any packages in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, package, rjava

I'm very new to R and I'm having problems right off the bat. None of the packages want to load and each time I try, the same error message is being given (see below). What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

> library(xlsx)
>   Loading required package: rJava
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: fun(libname, pkgname)
>     error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
>   Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded

I have since added JAVA_HOME to my environmental variables but now when I attempt to load a package, a new error pops up (See Below)

> library(xlsx)
>   Loading required package: rJava
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
>     call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
>     error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Sam/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
>     LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded

Comment: You're probably missing the  JAVA_HOME environment variable - have you checked whether it exists? - Or Java is maybe not installed at all...

Comment: And have you installed Java?

Comment: Java is installed and I added the JRE_HOME but not JAVA_HOME - I'm installing the development kit now and will see if that works! :)

Comment: If you're using 64-bit R, make sure you install 64-bit Java as well, not 32-bit.

Comment: That was the problem!! Thank you Hong Ooi and thardes2! :D